# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' to data type bit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, checkbox

when i check on checkbox whose datatype is bit ,its value i.e 1 or 0 is not being store in database it is giving error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' to data type bit

```
if (CheckBoxDT.Checked) 
{ 
    cmd.CommandText = " Insert into ClientMaster(doTips) values ( 1 )";    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("doTips", bool.Parse("1")); 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
} 
else 
{ 
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into ClientMaster(doTips) values (0)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("doTips", bool.Parse("0")); 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

Comment: show us some code pls!

Comment: and your table structure(screenshot)

Comment: i have added this code to convert checkbox into bit but it is not working giving same error..............                                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxDL" runat="server" Checked='<%#(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("isActive"))) %>' style="color: #FFFFFF" />

Comment: What's your database column name?

Comment: What is "isActive"? Is that a column name? If yes, then are you trying to pass a datatable row value to the "Checked" attribute of your checkbox?

Comment: Are you using Sqldatasource, ObjectDatasource etc. controls or pure ADO.Net code?

Comment: Check my edits and let me know if you didn't find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting Bit value to the database

```
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@check", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToInt16(CheckBoxDT.Checked);
```

retrieving selected check boxes  Try this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxDT" runat="server" Checked='<%#((bool)Eval("isActive"))%>'
                        Style="color: #FFFFFF" />
```

[image]

Your code

```
if (CheckBoxDT.Checked) 
{ 
cmd.CommandText = " Insert into ClientMaster(doTips) values ( 1 )";    
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("doTips", bool.Parse("1")); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
} 
else 
{ 
cmd.CommandText = "insert into ClientMaster(doTips) values (0)"; 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("doTips", bool.Parse("0")); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

Replace this with

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into ClientMaster(doTips) values (@doTips)"; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@doTips", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToInt16(CheckBoxDT.Checked)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: when i write this code in .cs file it wont work either
  `
if (CheckBoxDT.Checked)
          {
              cmd.CommandText = " Insert into ClientMaster(doTips) values ( 1 )";
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("doTips", bool.Parse("1"));

              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          }

          else
          {
              cmd.CommandText = "insert into ClientMaster(doTips) values (0)";
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("doTips", bool.Parse("0"));


              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          } `

Comment: Why you are parsing to `bool value` when your data type is `bit`

Comment: well it is not giving error but in database checkbox field have this value instead of 1 or 0 , System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote with my code that didn't happen as I posted the working image too

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you're passing the control, rather than the value of its state; you should be passing the state, and converting that explicitly if necessary:

```
CheckBox         // a web control, and no standard db type to represent it
CheckBox.Checked // a boolean value, generally translatable to db bit
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably passing the actual control to your database and not the state of it. You need to use `myCheckBox.Checked` instead of just `myCheckBox`.